# Python FastAPI putting everything in main()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi, uvicorn

In Python, I want to be able to write all my application methods in `def main()` and lastly just run the `if __name__`, but this way the [FastAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastAPI) [Swagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_(software)) UI gives an error:

> No operations defined in spec!

Basically, my code is something like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

def main():
    @app.get("/fast")
    async def fast(target: str, input_time: float):
        return (target, input_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or just simply:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @app.get("/fast")
    async def fast(target: str, input_time: float):
        return (target, input_time)
```

Comment: check [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/#call-uvicorn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try like this**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/fast")
async def fast(target: str, input_time: float):
    return (target, input_time)
```

**Now run like this**

uvicorn file_name:app --reload